# Preventing iframe reload upon move between components reactjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, iframe

I have a main component that have two child components and we move between them based on some conditions. Child components have an array of `iframe`. When I move between them, the `iframe`'s reload again. I want to prevent reloading `iframe`'s when their URL haven't changed. I use `useMemo` and `React.memo` but this didn't work properly. I found the below question, but in that solution, the `iframe` was hidden.
Do you have a solution for this?
Thanks

I share my code here:

App.tsx (my main component)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import IframeComponent from './IframeComponent';
import SecondIFrameComponent from './SecondIFrameComponent';

function App() {
   const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);

   const toggleIframe = () => {
       setToggle(prevToggle => !prevToggle);
   };

   return (
      <div>
         <button onClick={toggleIframe}>Toggle Iframe</button>
           {toggle ? <IframeComponent key="iframe1" 
            url="www.example.com" /> : <SecondIFrameComponent 
            key="iframe2" url="www.example2.com" />}
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

IframeComponent:

```
import React, { memo } from 'react';

 const IframeComponent = memo(({ url ,key}:any) => {
   return <iframe key={key} src={url} />;
  });

 export default IframeComponent;
```

SecondFrameComponent:

```
import React, { memo } from 'react';

const SecondIFrameComponent = memo(({ url,key }:any) => {
    return <iframe key={key} src={url} />;
});

export default SecondIFrameComponent;
```

Comment: You don't really have any options beyond hiding it. You could make it so that they are not all loaded at the start, but instead, if you visit it it will be inserted, and then it will be kept in DOM but hidden if they switch away, and be visible when they come back. That way, you would avoid hitting them all at once when the component loads and instead you'd only be keeping around what the user has already seen (harmless). You need to post code to help further.

Comment: @adsy Thanks for your comment. I shared my code in the question. The 'iframe' always rerender when I move between components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because when you are switching between components, you are literally removing one iframe from the page and inserting the other.

You may not like using CSS to hide/show them instead of React. However, I'm afraid it is your only option in this case. React isn't designed to hide and show iframes.